# jasper reports export to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, report

I am using display tags in jsp to create pdf reports using itext-1.3.jar and in the same project am using jasper reports 3.0 to create pdf reports which requires itext 2.1.0 or above to create pdf reports because in itext-1.3.jar com.lowagie.text.pdfWriter is missing functions which are required for export to pdf in jasper reports.Now if I use itext 1.3.jar, the jasper reports are not working and is throwing error for missing com.lowagie.text.pdfWriter.setTransparencyBlend function and if i use itext  2.1 or above then the dispay tags reports are not working throwing output stream  has been already called exception and if I use both jars then only jasper reports export to pdf is working. Can there be  a way to resolve this issue as both reports are required. Moreover jasper reports is being used in order to get Arabic data which was not possible using display tags.

Comment: Your question is not clear and lacks a lot of details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use only one version of iText. If you use more than one version, then errors are guaranteed. Preferably use version 5.5.11 (released 20 Mar 2017) because 1.3.0 was released on 6 Apr 2005 (12 years ago) and 2.1.0 was released on on 27 Mar 2008 (9 years ago). That is very, very old and deprecated, many many bugs have been fixed since. Check on the website of Jasper Reports which version is compatible with iText 5.5.11 and make sure that your licenses are ok (but that is not a technical matter and outside the scope of Stack Overflow).